# How to pass token in query firestore angular

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to pass token in query of firestore and I search a lot but i didn't get the answer

any body can help me  please

```
addData(tableName, data){
       let token = localstorage.getIteam("token")
       return this.db.collection(`${tableName}/`).add(data);
    }
```

Comment: Are you missing `data.token = token` in your code?

Comment: Can you please tell me how to add token

Comment: That's what the line in my comment does. What problem do you have after adding that line to your code? Can you edit your question to show how you used it?